# how to handle paste operation when the ag-grid has no rows?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

In our AG Grid implementation. Sometimes we have an empty grid that has no rows at all.

In that case, how we trigger the Ctrl+V and trigger the paste operation?

According to the docs [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-grid/clipboard/#paste-from-clipboard), it said that you have to either have a row/range focus to trigger the ctrl-v paste callback.

Alternatively, I have added a paste command on the context menu. But, in this case how to get the clipboard contents?

Any suggestion on how to do that.